# date.js .parse() Not Working With ISO8601 Time Zone Offset

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I'm working on some JavaScript with [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).

```
var event_schedule_datetime = data.events[i].schedule[0].datetime;
var event_schedule_datetime_readable = Date.parse(event_schedule_datetime).toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy @ h:mm tt');
```

`event_schedule_datetime` is in ISO8601 format (2013-11-03T09:00:00+01:00).  I assumed that date.js would be able to interpret that format, but I keep getting `Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference`.  The same thing happens if I replace `event_schedule_datetime` with `2013-11-01T18:00:00+01:00`.

I know the variable has the correct data, as it's referenced in another place and results in `<time datetime="2013-11-01T18:00:00+01:00">2013-11-01T18:00:00+01:00</time>`.  Basically, I'm trying to give the viewer a human-readable date and time.

I also found that removing the time zone offset does work.

```
var event_schedule_datetime_readable = Date.parse(event_schedule_datetime.substring(0, 19)).toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy @ h:mm tt');
```

So, it seems that date.js just doesn't like offset when working with ISO8601.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the native Date object can handle this:

Console output:

```
> new Date('2013-11-03T09:00:00+01:00')
Sun Nov 03 2013 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
> new Date('2013-11-03T09:00:00+01:00').toISOString()
"2013-11-03T08:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: And then passing that `.toISOString()` to date.js?

Comment: Hmmm...  That didn't work as I assumed it would.  `var event_schedule_datetime_utc = new Date(event_schedule_datetime).toISOString();` `var event_schedule_datetime_readable = Date.parse(event_schedule_datetime_utc).toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy @ h:mm tt');` still resulted in `to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference`.